# for loops on openmp

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

The following code is running faster when I dont use openMP. Why is it so?
I am running it on a dual core machine.
The time taken to run using open mp is about 0.05 sec while it takes only 0.03 sec when I run it without openMP.

```
#include<omp.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
clock_t start=clock();
int i,j,t1,t2, n=1;
float a[1000][1000];
float b[1000][1000];



#pragma omp parallel 
{
#pragma omp for private(i)
for(j=0; j<1000; j++)
{
    for(i=0; i<1000; i++)


    {
            a[i][j]=(i*j*i*j)/(i+j+1)/(i*j*i+8*i+1);
            b[i][j]=(i*j*i*j)/(i+j+1)/(i*j*i+8*i+1);

    }
}
}
clock_t end=clock();
cout<<"Time to run is "<<(double)(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<endl;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, but you should consider the size of the problem. 1000*1000*4 bytes(float) = 4MB. This is usually a size of combined L2 cache on most mordern system. The  parallelisation overhead in static cases is around some cpu cycles (100-999cycles). So the performance increment you actually achieve via parallel is lost by this overhead. If you change your problem to say 10000*100000 then the problem is memory bound, the change in performance then is very much evident.

Comment: okay. Thanks for the information. In addition, I also found that the clock() function will end up giving the total time taken by the process, including the time taken by each of the threads. Maybe, thats why I ended up measuring the wall time incorrectly.

Comment: The time consumed should be calculated for all the threads, then we see how good the parallelization is ?. Say you have at total "W" amount work to do, when running with **n** thread, each thread will do **W/n** and collectively the time should decrease by the factor (1/n). If it doesn't, then  we inspect the algorithm. For future reference, put your time start just before the loop start and end after the loop end. The memory layout in c++ arrays is along the columns. i.e. for element a[i][j] the next neighbour is a[i][j+1]. So you should change the outer loop to "i" instead of "j".